# Firefox 19.0.2 deletes proxy extension file

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Working on Windows 8 64bit, Firefox 19.0.2.
I went to `.../Firefox/Profiles/.../extensions` and put my `ekons@www.solver.ws` file containing
a string

```
h:\myextensions\ekons\
```

The directory h:\myextensions\ekons\ contains install.rdf file of my extension.

Every time I restart Firefox, it deletes `.../Firefox/Profiles/.../extensions/ekons@www.solver.ws` file. Of course, without trying to install the extension.

Any suggestions?

**Addition**
I attach an image FF extensions directory.
[image]

Comment: sounds like you're triggering a security mechanism, perhaps you should try registering your extension through the browser's built in add-on manager?

Comment: Yes, but all I do is by specification: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Firefox_extension_proxy_file

Comment: I can't speak for Windows 8, but are you sure you're in the right Profiles directory? In Windows 7, there are actually two locations: one in **Users/../AppData/Local** and one in **Users/../AppData/Roaming**. The latter is the one to use (i.e. the _extensions_ directory should already exist). You might also try changing your GUID to something different (whatever@example.com) and see if that helps. Perhaps the .ws file extension is biting you somehow?

Comment: I tried to install one of my extensions that worked on Windows 7 on earlier FF versions. I always tested my extensions in such a way - putting proxy file in profile directory. Now it does not work. Is it Win8 or FF19 problem?

Comment: One way to test would be to install a Firefox 18 (or earlier) binary, create a new profile to use with said install, and try it with that profile. I can load extensions using this method in Windows 7 and Firefox 19 with no problem, so I'm guessing it's a Windows 8 security setting (or something similar).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it was my mistake: extension file name was not the same as ID inside install.rdf.
Such files are silently deleted by FireFox from profile directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same isue, the problem was an extra tag </em:description> in the install.rdf file.
When it was a valid XML all goes ok.